# Display TODO on non .NET languages in Task List?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am working on XSLT files that I added TODO blocks. These blocks doesn't get displayed on the Task List. I have researched on found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-the-task-list?view=vs-2019), but the custom tokens only still works for .net languages. Any means/extensions that I can use to have this one enabled?

Comment: "Any means/extensions that I can use to have this one enabled?" - you'll need to write a custom VS extension, sorry.